# How to export Java Native Module in React Library

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a react native library with *react-native-create-library*
 command. Also, I've added a new class extending ReactContextBaseJavaModule and a class extending ReactPackage(I removed the existing ones created by default with CLI command). And I don't really understand how React is going to get the native module. There is no MainApplication class like in this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android, so I don't know where to add my Package. When I pack my library with *npm pack* I always get null when I try to get the module. How do I export a native module?